# Настройка .htaccess перенаправления

Tags: .htaccess

Для сайта мне нужно сделать следующее:

1. с url вида `http://site.name/static/***` надо убирать `static`, то есть `http://site.name/static/css/styles.css` в должен читаться как `http://site.name/css/styles.css`
2. по URL `http://site.name/api`, `http://site.name/static` и `http://site.name/admin` выдавать файлы, находящиеся по соответственным папкам: `api`, `static`, `admin`;
3. все остальные запросы перенаправлять на `http://site.name/index.html`.

Пока что я делаю это так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /static/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/

RewriteRule .*? static/index.html
```

Однако, если сделать запрос к, примеру, `http://site.name/css/test.css`, а этого файла не существует, то открывается `http://site.name/index.html`, вместо выдачи ошибки `404`, хотя должно. То есть мне нужно, чтобы с папки `static` выдавались ошибки `404, 403` и т. д. + `static` c `url` надо убирать.

Как мне это сделать? Сколько вариантов не пробовал, всё никак не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста.